# ¿Cómo seleccionar valores de una tabla del tipo bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el sgte query el cual me filtra las personas que finalizaron un curso, y cuyo campo está definido como bit, es decir si finalizó el curso es 1 y si no finalizó es cero; pero en el query sólo me arroja los que finalizaron, es decir "1" y los valores con "0" no me trae ninguno.

```
  select distinct Participantes.nombre,Participantes.apellido,
  Participantes.Cedula,Participantes.Celular, cursoes.nombre, 
   CursoPlaneadoes.Numero, CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo, 
  Cursoes.Descripcion
  from respuestas, CursoPlaneadoParticipantes, CursoPlaneadoes, 
  Participantes,Cursoes, Preguntas
   where Cursoes.Nombre = 'Mujer Valiosa' AND CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Id 
   = respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
  and CursoPlaneadoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.CursoPlaneadoId
  and Participantes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.ParticipanteId
  and Cursoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoes.CursoId
     and CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo in (0,1)
```

Comment: por que no selecciones cuando el valor no sea "1" 
sql transforma cualquier valor que no sea 0 en 1 al insertar en un campo tipo bit, tal vez los valores 0 no fueron incertados

Comment: Tienes muchas condiciones en la consulta y se puede dar la casualidad de que los que respeten todas esas condiciones sólo tengan el bit en 1. Si no es el caso, intenta añadir algun ejemplo de la información que contiene la tabla

Comment: Es posible que los datos no se muestren debido a otra condición que se cumple previamente a `in (0,1)` la cual saca fuera de los resultados los valores con `0`. Una forma de encontrar el problema sería ir ejecutando la consulta por partes, yendo de lo particular a lo general, hasta detectar dónde está el problema. Por ejemplo, prueba 1º esta consulta: `select * FROM  CursoPlaneadoParticipantes  where CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo in (0,1);` y luego le vas agregando cada criterio.

Comment: Como han dicho otros comentarios, puede haber muchos motivos para esto. Quizás todos finalizaron el curso `Mujer Valiosa`, por ejemplo. Por otro lado, no veo el motivo por el cual hacer join con las tablas `Preguntas` y `Respuestas`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utlizando left joins como muestro en la consulta más abajo. **Excluí la tabla Preguntas porque no tiene relación con ninguna otra y te estaba haciendo un cross join (producto cartesiano) en tu consulta**

```
select distinct     Participantes.nombre,
                    Participantes.apellido,
                    Participantes.Cedula,
                    Participantes.Celular, 
                    cursoes.nombre, 
                    CursoPlaneadoes.Numero, 
                    CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo,    
                    Cursoes.Descripcion
from respuestas
left join CursoPlaneadoParticipantes
  on CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Id = respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
left join CursoPlaneadoes
  on CursoPlaneadoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.CursoPlaneadoId  
left join Participantes
  on Participantes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.ParticipanteId
left join Cursoes
  on Cursoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoes.CursoId
where Cursoes.Nombre = 'Mujer Valiosa' 
  and CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Finalizo in (0)
```

Fíjate cuáles valores vienen null para determinar porqué tu join no funciona cuando la columna Finalizó es igual a cero.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu rta probé ese query pero no me trae nada, es decir hace la consulta pero no me trae los valores en cero.

Comment: Quítale el filtro Cursoes.Nombre = 'Mujer Valiosa'  y fíjate a ver